# Split issue with model_time and timetk in R

Tags: r, panel-data, forecast, tidymodels

I'm using modeltime to forecast 20 time series (not balanced) at once using [Modeltime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime/vignettes/getting-started-with-modeltime.html) package. However, when I call the function modeltime_calibrate i got the following error:

> Error in `glubort()`: ! Missing 'new_data'. Try adding a test data set
> using rsample::testing(splits). See help for more info:
> ?modeltime_calibrate

Its seems to be related to split, but I couldn't find any explanation:

> > splits <Analysis/Assess/Total> <887/20/907>

Follow my code.
Thanks,
Rick

```
splits <- data %>% time_series_split(assess = "3 months", cumulative = TRUE)
splits %>%
  tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
  plot_time_series_cv_plan(date, value, .interactive = TRUE)

rec_obj <- recipe(value ~ ., training(splits)) %>%
  step_mutate(ID = droplevels(ID)) %>%
  step_timeseries_signature(date) %>%
  step_rm(date) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors(), one_hot = TRUE)
summary(prep(rec_obj))

wflw_xgb <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(
    boost_tree() %>% set_engine("xgboost")
  ) %>%
  add_recipe(rec_obj) %>%
  fit(training(splits))
wflw_xgb

model_tbl <- modeltime_table(
  wflw_xgb
)
model_tbl

calib_tbl <- model_tbl %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(
    new_data = testing(splits), 
    id       = "ID",
    modeltime_calibrate(quiet = FALSE)
  )
calib_tbl
```

Data:

> dput(data2)
> structure(list(date = structure(c(1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800,
> 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400,
> 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800,
> 1648771200, 1651363200, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200,
> 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400,
> 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200,
> 1651363200, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200,
> 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800,
> 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200,
> 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800,
> 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000,
> 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200,
> 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400,
> 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200,
> 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400,
> 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200,
> 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400, 1543622400,
> 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800, 1559347200,
> 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400, 1575158400,
> 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200, 1590969600,
> 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 1606780800,
> 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600,
> 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800,
> 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1609459200,
> 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600,
> 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200,
> 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1506816000, 1509494400,
> 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800,
> 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400,
> 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800,
> 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400,
> 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200,
> 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800,
> 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200,
> 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800,
> 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200,
> 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400, 1543622400, 1546300800,
> 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800, 1559347200, 1561939200,
> 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400, 1575158400, 1577836800,
> 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600,
> 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200,
> 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600,
> 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200,
> 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1420070400, 1422748800,
> 1425168000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200,
> 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600,
> 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200,
> 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1609459200, 1612137600,
> 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000,
> 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600,
> 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800,
> 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200,
> 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000,
> 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600,
> 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800,
> 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400,
> 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800,
> 1648771200, 1651363200, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400,
> 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000,
> 1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400,
> 1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000,
> 1538352000, 1541030400, 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400,
> 1554076800, 1556668800, 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000,
> 1569888000, 1572566400, 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800,
> 1585699200, 1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400,
> 1601510400, 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800,
> 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400,
> 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800,
> 1648771200, 1651363200, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400,
> 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600,
> 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800,
> 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000,
> 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800,
> 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000,
> 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800,
> 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000,
> 1541030400, 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800,
> 1556668800, 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000,
> 1572566400, 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200,
> 1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400,
> 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200,
> 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400,
> 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200,
> 1651363200, 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800,
> 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400,
> 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800,
> 1648771200, 1651363200, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400,
> 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600,
> 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800,
> 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000,
> 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800,
> 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000,
> 1509494400, 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800,
> 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000,
> 1541030400, 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800,
> 1556668800, 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000,
> 1572566400, 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200,
> 1588291200, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400,
> 1604188800, 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200,
> 1619827200, 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400,
> 1635724800, 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200,
> 1651363200, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400,
> 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000,
> 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800,
> 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400,
> 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800,
> 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000, 1509494400,
> 1512086400, 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800,
> 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400,
> 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800,
> 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400,
> 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200,
> 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800,
> 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200,
> 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800,
> 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200,
> 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800,
> 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000,
> 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200,
> 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400,
> 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200,
> 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400,
> 1514764800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200,
> 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400, 1543622400,
> 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800, 1559347200,
> 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400, 1575158400,
> 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200, 1590969600,
> 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800, 1606780800,
> 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1622505600,
> 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800, 1638316800,
> 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200, 1525132800,
> 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 1538352000, 1541030400,
> 1543622400, 1546300800, 1548979200, 1551398400, 1554076800, 1556668800,
> 1559347200, 1561939200, 1564617600, 1567296000, 1569888000, 1572566400,
> 1575158400, 1577836800, 1580515200, 1583020800, 1585699200, 1588291200,
> 1590969600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1598918400, 1601510400, 1604188800,
> 1606780800, 1609459200, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1619827200,
> 1622505600, 1625097600, 1627776000, 1630454400, 1633046400, 1635724800,
> 1638316800, 1640995200, 1643673600, 1646092800, 1648771200, 1651363200
> ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value = c(2083932,
> 1950171, 1980926, 2461828, 2100801, 1933544, 2233212, 2281489,
> 2332978, 2435590, 2324081, 2203801, 2086510, 1956418, 1905085,
> 1701513, 1701002, 6972.461, 6225.307, 6277.703, 6806.333, 457963.4,
> 9247.682, 32677.13, 12119.93, 24109.31, 178369.4, 46707.13, 116648,
> 8813.909, 12592.63, 23458.46, 17243.99, 41718.48, 138753.3, 147283.9,
> 159596.9, 162527.9, 172139, 186912.8, 199447.8, 211219.8, 220876.7,
> 229026.5, 240222.2, 258874.8, 269721.6, 281965.2, 301389.2, 315747.9,
> 339189.8, 181553, 183511, 178432, 170117, 174254, 157093, 155940,
> 148820, 138293, 140852, 136471, 148723, 125715, 124786, 120678,
> 117131, 121437, 117071, 119393, 110149, 102997, 105716, 100807,
> 113581, 123014, 125888, 120772, 122770, 117110, 118830, 127888,
> 126463, 128019, 131106, 132461, 138721, 152699, 137878, 149970,
> 143298, 147116, 145526, 145869, 147309, 148051, 153455, 147045,
> 163636, 151536, 143592, 142710, 144018, 169477, 191491, 193601,
> 182294, 183088, 181907, 165129, 196131, 189404, 181571, 180107,
> 183752, 190208, 189822, 184403, 186700, 143214, 229631, 204574,
> 208789, 204674.7, 198314.6, 190151.9, 192424.7, 401053.8, 389546.8,
> 378793.3, 58621.6, 56900.61, 58544.35, 53683.21, 54619.97, 52336.17,
> 52125.07, 49019.01, 50733.09, 48224.08, 114230, 73488.5, 78062,
> 66257.18, 63709.47, -63834.9, -69282.6, -34674.5, -21494.4, 158682.7,
> 85341.02, 18014.91, 11915.6, 13481.26, 30411.9, 15942.67, 18123.67,
> 67, 4707, 3830, 2662, 4826, 7721, 8574, 6105, 9574, 15969, 24515,
> 23750, 24859, 29581, 36583, 37539, 35040, 38145, 33826, 39403,
> 43919, 48045, 52710, 49241, 50587, 51965, 62260, 58783, 58935,
> 51637, 42407, 50253, 45102, 49212, 46878, 48166, 50818, 51589,
> 57052, 68370.13, 83220.78, 71789.06, 84793.53, 83499.91, 92959.89,
> 110604.4, 113749.3, 116861.6, 118703.6, 114356.9, 133689.8, 107931.9,
> 134176.7, 119300.7, 118410.6, 121198.6, 7, 2, 209, 738, 1500,
> 2598, 2836, 4013, 4547, 6752, 9808, 13200, 16434, 21976, 32610,
> 42498, 54298, 57261, 63159, 65965, 68626, 71571, 69324, 70684,
> 68006, 69319, 70595, 70615, 73321, 65882.01, 70125.35, 73302.44,
> 72151.86, 74019.36, 73480.6, 77689.52, 73955.09, 71458.99, 79560.74,
> 77714.22, 87302.14, 388843, 151880.8, 199528.4, 158357.5, 179707.5,
> 5855, 3734, 3016, 20000, 93, 51228, 152593, 147707.3, 152342.3,
> 170402.7, 195926.9, 169838.8, 185421.8, 208586.4, 232198.2, 235424,
> 278144.2, 239536.8, 274178, 229447.4, 201875.7, 197140.7, 176340,
> 199179, 10629.22, 11069.22, 76920.18, 49681.47, 54629.24, 41784.58,
> 23420.33, 66861.4, 46128.38, 160298, 55595.37, 24998.86, 42793.85,
> 190414, 121946.5, 15236.71, 250271.1, 263481.5, 900230.2, 12519.21,
> 3846.68, 80.13, 99, 99, 99, 99, 5500, 60.75, 336.5468, 2658.514,
> 17473.36, 31903.92, 42934.65, 64549.45, 42786.9, 64528.09, 68950.21,
> 62334.35, 78381.29, 76575.28, 79843.12, 63637.71, 67945.82, 66400.98,
> 70852.86, 80654.77, 82728.91, 84920.54, 78872.71, 74230.72, 79718.15,
> 70278.81, 77311.33, 65477.07, 63883.88, 60920.48, 59463.09, 63588.72,
> 3, -14, 116, 32, 725, 7957, 5260, 7544, 7036, 9859, 11450, 12855,
> 15742, 14366, 17234, 17514, 16319, 19743, 19459, 21566, 23887,
> 24344, 26813, 25112, 32070, 33459, 25350, 32571, 30693, 33469,
> 31755, 32790, 33605, 28326, 34746, 55690, 23516, 25299, 28292,
> 25978, 22095, 26011, 26198, 26532, 37058, 39477, 39097, 40383,
> 43719, 43858.15, 44768.15, 47912.44, 58174.46, 58314.08, 56466.82,
> 58165.62, 50670.24, 45213.39, 51334.23, 45132.34, 51714.14, 39140.62,
> 35521.31, 35131.7, 32224.89, 32599.64, 1265237, 1233457, 1296608,
> 1297813, 1198245, 1213322, 1239841, 1223294, 1276484, 1354942,
> 1372216, 1487684, 1384082, 1427289, 1419981, 1558989, 1536445,
> 1537975, 1528473, 1547607, 1611710, 1485140, 1487032, 1484354,
> 1411420, 1430510, 1517915, 1499737, 1523590, 1511891, 1532000,
> 1587068, 1533391, 1541699, 1506859, 1552920, 1441443, 1422334,
> 1439888, 1438811, 1396145, 1395038, 1375798, 1362614, 1326090,
> 1329000, 1244732, 1354162, 1216691, 1173415, 1176548, 1141411,
> 1066206, 1019118, 988499, 1001852, 901223, 930559, 863214, 904869,
> 806624, 789492, 775546, 752936, 748191, 733050, 732415, 707040,
> 678413, 654274, 666637, 663248, 590168.2, 612531.1, 600121.2,
> 582241.1, 591551.2, 572399.3, 558498.5, 525632.6, 530394, 526828.8,
> 383121.9, 362122.4, 368189.3, 347611.9, 346074.6, 339376.3, 337119.3,
> 20000, 13630, 132508.9, 875124.9, 1336834, 1598590, 1656514,
> 1920719, 2433575, 1918492, 1399765, 1160387, 1018087, 1000060,
> 1000407, 844354.6, 868914.5, 755539.4, 793827.8, 108750, 97225,
> 95533, 65371, 64017, 63117, 76913, 78131, 70477, 79362, 75902,
> 89955, 93884, 91481, 97189, 92807, 33600, 85593, 96928, 94048,
> 90721, 91553, 83804, 185770, 106780, 98345, 106698, 92279, 84154,
> 84532, 91128, 90685, 95075, 84203, 81623, 91576, 86581, 80576,
> 87585, 74325, 67120, 77766, 83139, 76859, 74956, 70956, 66650,
> 94019, 77882, 66361, 68573, 57188, 53975, 57676, 53441, 53591,
> 53797, 57749, 51933, 76797, 38184, 34550, 38329, 25439, 25826,
> 40405, 76945, 26897, 17088, 34842, 25011, 27660, 33902.41, 45435.43,
> 43605.72, 51204.28, 50339.34, 54299.58, 58077.71, 55829.12, 46393.98,
> 55530.54, 53173.71, 39094.48, 62973.63, 52255.38, 48705.67, 34063.43,
> 41231.58, 80920, 75024, 69198, 69131, 76573, 76219, 91797, 103054,
> 110183, 123885, 123468, 134442, 139281, 147540, 155182, 187975,
> 172145, 204750, 233247, 236003, 286992, 279767, 287995, 335349,
> 307508, 344059, 341206, 366931, 374969, 415748, 443059, 462397,
> 498197, 481533, 499971, 520237, 458758, 448274, 491779, 406120,
> 437307, 469965, 409020, 425137, 474399, 362592, 406261, 411975,
> 328467, 319335, 395716, 242726, 311600, 385376, 219880, 238926,
> 135465, 180974, 194343, 170154, 174062, 254612, 102527, 163510,
> 242587, 96332, 160346, 165524, 170899, 255716, 98249, 171123,
> 265813.4, 176660.1, 76303.95, 156814.9, 160126.4, 161155.2, 229082.6,
> 90114.06, 147917.2, 210152.1, 100151.9, 142053, 143008.3, 114483.3,
> 125425.2, 126261.2, 118942, 5099, 5090, 5100, 3104, 3136, 3105,
> 3152, 3539, 3511, 3625, 5551, 6049, 5911, 6639, 7795, 10860,
> 12409, 14373, 18238, 19337, 24101, 23549, 26573, 47556, 36839,
> 32603, 40394, 38388, 40688, 41343, 49460, 48082, 50576, 65597,
> 57927, 60619, 57896, 57731, 49487, 57172, 64667, 59878, 58185,
> 58663, 59077, 57329, 57258, 53836, 45980, 49201, 48898, 46642,
> 43119, 41641, 39429, 37460, 40300, 32335, 44302, 37277, 34744,
> 33753, 31581, 33095, 48197, 32721, 33106, 33773, 45147, 34405,
> 33266, 35361, 33138.96, 33652.35, 41994.9, 48588.7, 49100.3,
> 45410.89, 46317.88, 45240.67, 42217.39, 41093.69, 37168.68, 36655.65,
> 33175.78, 32024.01, 38002.98, 33357.68, 28974.01, 33, 11781,
> 50817, 82293, 118641, 112754, 112131, 133472, 131598, 129799,
> 172241, 115247, 127161, 129828, 133895, 140692, 138041, 138859,
> 134777, 160361, 139706, 142114, 121942, 107380, 126223, 96955,
> 92907, 82222, 87763, 95132, 99504, 122739, 144682.7, 144029.7,
> 127644.2, 117313.8, 118433.2, 126402.6, 147662.4, 152417.9, 154328,
> 219567.4, 88241.14, 167967.7, 215814.9, 202348.8, 250632.2, 261665.9,
> 270071.3), idn = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
> 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
> 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
> 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
> 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
> 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
> 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
> 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
> 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
> 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
> 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
> 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
> 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
> 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
> 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L,
> 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,
> 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
> 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,
> 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L,
> 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
> 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,
> 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,
> 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,
> 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,
> 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,
> 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), row.names = c(75L,
> 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L,
> 89L, 90L, 91L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L,
> 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 188L, 189L,
> 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L,
> 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L,
> 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L,
> 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L,
> 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L,
> 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L,
> 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L,
> 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L,
> 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L,
> 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L,
> 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L,
> 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 377L,
> 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L,
> 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L,
> 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L,
> 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L,
> 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 432L,
> 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 443L,
> 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L,
> 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L,
> 466L, 467L, 468L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 543L,
> 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L,
> 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L,
> 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 663L,
> 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 680L, 681L,
> 682L, 683L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L,
> 693L, 694L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L,
> 750L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 754L, 755L, 756L, 757L, 784L, 785L, 786L,
> 787L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 797L,
> 798L, 799L, 800L, 801L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 805L, 806L, 807L, 808L,
> 809L, 810L, 811L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 815L, 816L, 817L, 818L, 819L,
> 820L, 821L, 822L, 823L, 824L, 825L, 826L, 827L, 828L, 829L, 830L,
> 831L, 832L, 833L, 834L, 835L, 836L, 837L, 838L, 839L, 840L, 841L,
> 842L, 843L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 847L, 848L, 849L, 880L, 881L, 882L,
> 883L, 884L, 885L, 886L, 887L, 888L, 889L, 890L, 891L, 892L, 893L,
> 894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 903L, 904L,
> 905L, 906L, 907L, 908L, 909L, 910L, 911L, 912L, 913L, 914L, 915L,
> 916L, 917L, 918L, 919L, 920L, 921L, 922L, 923L, 924L, 925L, 926L,
> 927L, 928L, 929L, 930L, 931L, 932L, 933L, 934L, 935L, 936L, 937L,
> 938L, 939L, 940L, 941L, 942L, 943L, 944L, 945L, 946L, 947L, 948L,
> 949L, 950L, 951L, 952L, 953L, 954L, 955L, 956L, 957L, 958L, 959L,
> 960L, 961L, 962L, 963L, 964L, 965L, 966L, 967L, 968L, 1052L,
> 1053L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 1057L, 1058L, 1059L, 1060L, 1061L,
> 1062L, 1063L, 1064L, 1065L, 1066L, 1067L, 1068L, 1069L, 1070L,
> 1151L, 1152L, 1153L, 1154L, 1155L, 1156L, 1157L, 1158L, 1159L,
> 1160L, 1161L, 1162L, 1163L, 1164L, 1165L, 1166L, 1167L, 1168L,
> 1169L, 1170L, 1171L, 1172L, 1173L, 1174L, 1175L, 1176L, 1177L,
> 1178L, 1179L, 1180L, 1181L, 1182L, 1183L, 1184L, 1185L, 1186L,
> 1187L, 1188L, 1189L, 1190L, 1191L, 1192L, 1193L, 1194L, 1195L,
> 1196L, 1197L, 1198L, 1199L, 1200L, 1201L, 1202L, 1203L, 1204L,
> 1205L, 1206L, 1207L, 1208L, 1209L, 1210L, 1211L, 1212L, 1213L,
> 1214L, 1215L, 1216L, 1217L, 1218L, 1219L, 1220L, 1221L, 1222L,
> 1223L, 1224L, 1225L, 1226L, 1227L, 1228L, 1229L, 1230L, 1231L,
> 1232L, 1233L, 1234L, 1235L, 1236L, 1237L, 1238L, 1239L, 1586L,
> 1587L, 1588L, 1589L, 1590L, 1591L, 1592L, 1593L, 1594L, 1595L,
> 1596L, 1597L, 1598L, 1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 1602L, 1603L, 1604L,
> 1605L, 1606L, 1607L, 1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 1612L, 1613L,
> 1614L, 1615L, 1616L, 1617L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 1621L, 1622L,
> 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 1630L, 1631L,
> 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 1639L, 1640L,
> 1641L, 1642L, 1643L, 1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 1647L, 1648L, 1649L,
> 1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L,
> 1659L, 1660L, 1661L, 1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 1667L,
> 1668L, 1669L, 1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1846L, 1847L,
> 1848L, 1849L, 1850L, 1851L, 1852L, 1853L, 1854L, 1855L, 1856L,
> 1857L, 1858L, 1859L, 1860L, 1861L, 1862L, 1863L, 1864L, 1865L,
> 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 1872L, 1873L, 1874L,
> 1875L, 1876L, 1877L, 1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1881L, 1882L, 1883L,
> 1884L, 1885L, 1886L, 1887L, 1888L, 1889L, 1890L, 1891L, 1892L,
> 1893L, 1894L, 1895L, 1896L, 1897L, 1898L, 1899L, 1900L, 1901L,
> 1902L, 1903L, 1904L, 1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 1909L, 1910L,
> 1911L, 1912L, 1913L, 1914L, 1915L, 1916L, 1917L, 1918L, 1919L,
> 1920L, 1921L, 1922L, 1923L, 1924L, 1925L, 1926L, 1927L, 1928L,
> 1929L, 1930L, 1931L, 1932L, 1933L, 1934L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L,
> 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L,
> 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L,
> 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L,
> 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2031L,
> 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 2040L,
> 2041L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Quinten I update the question with my data. Thank u so much.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Silva, I am sorry, but I can't reproduce your error. For the `summary(rec_obj)` I do already get an error.

Comment: Ok @Quinten. Tks. I'm still stuck... every time I update or change the dataset the package break. No worries I go for the loops